Strapi Custom Endpoint for Updating User Not Appearing in Admin Roles and Permissions
I'm trying to extend the users-permissions plugin in Strapi to add a custom endpoint for updating user information. However, the new endpoint is not appearing under the roles and permissions section in the admin panel.
Here's what I've done so far:
Created strapi-server.js in src/extensions/users-permissions/ with the following content:
const _ = require("lodash");
const utils = require("@strapi/utils");
const { ApplicationError, ValidationError } = utils.errors;

module.exports = (plugin) => {
  plugin.controllers.user.updateMe = async (ctx) => {
    // needs to be logged in
    if (!ctx.state.user || !ctx.state.user.id) {
      throw new ApplicationError("You need to be logged");
    }

    if (
      !_.has(ctx.request.body, "username") ||
      ctx.request.body.username === ""
    ) {
      throw new ValidationError("Invalid data");
    }
    const allowedProperties = ["username"];
    const bodyKeys = Object.keys(ctx.request.body);
    if (bodyKeys.filter((key) => !allowedProperties.includes(key)).length > 0) {
      throw new ValidationError("Invalid data");
    }

    const newBody = {};
    bodyKeys.map(
      (key) =>
        (newBody[key] = ctx.request.body[key].trim().replace(/[<>]/g, ""))
    );
    if (_.has(ctx.request.body, "username")) {
      const userWithSameUsername = await strapi
        .query("plugin::users-permissions.user")
        .findOne({ where: { username: ctx.request.body.username } });
      if (
        userWithSameUsername &&
        _.toString(userWithSameUsername.id) !== _.toString(ctx.state.user.id)
      ) {
        throw new ApplicationError("Username already taken");
      }
    }

    await strapi
      .query("plugin::users-permissions.user")
      .update({
        where: { id: ctx.state.user.id },
        data: newBody,
      })
      .then((res) => {
        ctx.response.body = { username: res.username };
        ctx.response.status = 200;
      });
  };

  plugin.routes["content-api"].routes.push({
    method: "PUT",
    path: "/user/me",
    handler: "user.updateMe",
    config: {
      prefix: "",
      policies: [],
    },
  });

  return plugin;
};

Registered the plugin in config/plugins.js:
module.exports = ({ env }) => ({
  email: {
    config: {
      provider: "nodemailer",
      providerOptions: {
        host: env("SMTP_HOST"),
        port: env("SMTP_PORT"),
        auth: {
          user: env("SMTP_USER"),
          pass: env("SMTP_PASS"),
        },
      },
      settings: {
        defaultFrom: env("SMTP_DEFAULT_FROM"),
        defaultReplyTo: env("SMTP_DEFAULT_REPLYTO"),
      },
    },
  },
  "users-permissions": {
    enabled: true,
    resolve: "./src/extensions/users-permissions",
  },
});

Logs from yarn develop:
[2024-07-08 17:25:07.365] http: GET /admin (12 ms) 200
[2024-07-08 17:25:07.485] http: GET /admin/project-type (14 ms) 200
[2024-07-08 17:25:07.561] http: POST /admin/renew-token (7 ms) 200
[2024-07-08 17:25:07.563] http: GET /admin/init (13 ms) 200
[2024-07-08 17:25:07.572] http: GET /admin/users/me (21 ms) 200
[2024-07-08 17:25:07.606] http: GET /admin/telemetry-properties (18 ms) 200
[2024-07-08 17:25:07.619] http: GET /admin/users/me/permissions (18 ms) 200
[2024-07-08 17:25:07.620] http: GET /admin/information (21 ms) 200
[2024-07-08 17:25:07.627] http: GET /admin/project-settings (22 ms) 200
[2024-07-08 17:25:07.635] http: GET /i18n/locales (7 ms) 200
[2024-07-08 17:25:07.691] http: GET /content-manager/components (5 ms) 200
[2024-07-08 17:25:07.705] http: GET /content-manager/content-types (12 ms) 200
[2024-07-08 17:25:09.264] http: GET /content-manager/init (8 ms) 200
[2024-07-08 17:25:09.280] http: GET /content-manager/content-types-settings (12 ms) 200
[2024-07-08 17:25:09.305] http: GET /content-manager/content-types/plugin::users-permissions.user/configuration (6 ms) 200
[2024-07-08 17:25:09.343] http: GET /content-manager/collection-types/plugin::users-permissions.user?page=1&pageSize=10&sort=username:ASC (10 ms) 200
[2024-07-08 17:25:12.515] http: GET /users-permissions/roles (9 ms) 200
[2024-07-08 17:25:13.362] http: GET /users-permissions/permissions (9 ms) 200
[2024-07-08 17:25:13.374] http: GET /users-permissions/routes (9 ms) 200
[2024-07-08 17:25:13.386] http: GET /users-permissions/roles/1 (10 ms) 200


I check under settings/users and permissions plugin/roles/Authenticated/user-permissions/user and there is not updateMe field.

What am I doing wrong?
Any help will be appreciated.
Note: I followed this tutorial.
Update: It seems to be issue with the latest version of strapi: 4.24.4, but downgrading causes other issues.

Hmm, does that mean that it works in older versions?

@Greg, thanks for the response. Yes, it worked on version 4.20.3 as in this repo from the tutorial https://github.com/peterlidee/NNAS/blob/changeusername/backend/package.json, but causes other issues, therefore downgrading the version is not an option.

For anyone else struggling with the issue updateMe field not appearing on strapi admin board.
Downgrading the versions worked for me.
 "@strapi/plugin-cloud": "4.20.4",
 "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.20.4",
 "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.20.4",
 "@strapi/provider-email-nodemailer": "^4.20.4",
 "@strapi/strapi": "4.20.4",

Otherwise you should need to create a separate route.
https://docs.strapi.io/dev-docs/backend-customization/routes
